Logistic regression and study design with multiple groups
We are working on a retrospective study investigating factors associated with post-surgery complications. Our patients are categorized into three groups: A) no complications, B) mild complications only, and C) severe complications.
We first built a logistic regression model using all patients, the outcome being “any complications”. We are now considering a second logistic model involving only Group A and C, and the outcome is “severe complications only”. We hope the second model would yield more dramatic results and would allow us to compare the factors of the two types of complications.
I wonder if our modeling approach is valid. Specifically, since we will remove Group B entirely in the second model, will people regard this as cherry-picking our participants and causing bias?
Thank you.

In your first attempt, you tried to differentiate group A against B or C. In your suggested 2nd attempt, you want to predict A vs. C. Why? Did you already try C vs. A or B (i.e. severe complications only against "the rest"? And why try to dichotomize? Why not try an ordered logistic regression? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit

You can try ordinal logistic model

Your problem here is that your outcome of interest is not actually binary. There are three possible outcomes (none, mild, severe). What you are effectively doing by running multiple binary logit models on different dichotomized versions of the dependent variable is mimicking the process of a single multinomial logit ("mlogit") model. In an mlogit model we treat the one category of the dependent variable (here "no complications") as the reference category and (more or less) run separate logit models, each looking at the factors associated with being in some other category as opposed to the reference category.
So here you would get one model (and one set of coefficients) telling you the factors associated with having mild complications (vs no complications) and another set of coefficients telling you the factors associated with having severe complications (vs no complications). There is no cherry picking here because you would present both sets of models, and if an independent variable is significant in one model, but not the other, then that is part of your result.
If you don't know how to run an mlogit model, then you can basically replicated it by doing what you describe, but the key is to report both results: mild vs none AND severe vs none.
Issues of cherry-picking (or "p hacking" more broadly) in statistics aren't about just running a bunch of related models, but about running a bunch of related models and then only presenting the ones that show results you like. So here, as long as you present both sets of models (which if you run an mlogit, happens automatically) you are fine.
p.s.: Note that this particular analyses won't actually tell you what factors are associated with having severe complications vs mild complications. If you wanted to answer that question you could re-run the mlogit model again, but treating "mild" as the reference category.
